# Empty view paths when using rspec to test a rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I'm having trouble getting rspec to render a view. The following error keeps getting returned when I run `rake spec`:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template spec/views/current_user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
```

The `Searched in:` part is what I suspect is going wrong, as it implies there are no view paths whatsoever defined.

Here's how the template is rendered:

```
render 'spec/views/current_user', :layout => false
```

And the dummy rails app is set up in `spec_helper.rb` with:

```
require 'rails'
require 'action_controller'
class TestRailsApp < Rails::Application
  config.secret_key_base = '1234'
  config.eager_load = false if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 4

  initialize!
end

module ApplicationHelper
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

If it helps, I'm trying to contribute to the [render_anywhere](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) gem, and I've asked in an issue there but not had a reply.

Comment: Can you include your test definition?

Comment: You can see the tests [here](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere/blob/master/spec/lib/render_anywhere_spec.rb)